# very simple form in block rendering incorrect values

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

I have a very simple code in block :

```
if ($vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('caller_details')) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');
  $output = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('taxonomy_form_term', $vocabulary));
}
echo $output;
```

the problem is that it sets the value of "name" in my form to taxonomy vocabulary name by default. Why is that?

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How is the form defined? Are you saving the form input in a vocabulary? If not, how is the form related to the vocabulary?

Comment: I've created vocabulary with fields shown above and now trying to render "add term" form of "Caller Details" vocabulary in the block thats shown on "create node" page. So to answer your questions - yes - input is saved in vocabulary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That form expects an array representing the current term as edited as its first argument. The vocabulary is the second argument. Add an empty array as first argument and you should be OK.

Comment: that worked beautifully! thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could `hook_form_alter()` this form in a custom module and set your default value to that element.

Comment: good point, however it will still remain intriguing why is it behaving like that.

Comment: it probably has a default value...

Comment: that was my first thought but no..